# Is there a way to use a proxy in Puppeteer for Firefox?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, web-crawler, puppeteer, http-proxy

Is there a way to configure Puppeteer to use a proxy with Firefox, without manually having to adjust my operating system's proxy settings?

I am able to accomplish this in Chrome by using the command line argument `args: [ '--proxy-server=http://0.0.0.0:0000' ]`, but Firefox doesn't seem to have this capability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no 'proxy-server' argument in Firefox.

However, you can intercept the request and set a proxy with the [puppeteer-proxy](https://github.com/gajus/puppeteer-proxy) library.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/gajus/puppeteer-proxy#usage).

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import { proxyRequest } from 'puppeteer-proxy';

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.setRequestInterception(true);

  page.on('request', async (request) => {
    await proxyRequest({
      page,
      proxyUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
      request,
    });
  });

  await page.goto('http://gajus.com');
})();
```

It will work in Chrome and Firefox as well.

Comment: Thank you!!  This is spot on what I was looking for.

Comment: Hey. Happy to help you. Accept the answer if it's solved your problem to help other people.

Comment: Hey, @Yevhen I tried using this approach with firefox but I get an error UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Navigation to https://www.google.com failed: NS_ERROR_FAILURE where my goto url is https://www.google.com. Do you have any clues as to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: hello, i have error using the method,  page.setRequestInterception(true);  throws error ProtocolError: Protocol error (Fetch.enable): Fetch.enable RemoteAgentError@chrome://remote/content/cdp/Error.jsm:31:5

Answer (score 4):

Proxies in Firefox can be configured via preferences. Here a list of these with their default values:

```
pref("network.proxy.ftp",                   "");
pref("network.proxy.ftp_port",              0);
pref("network.proxy.http",                  "");
pref("network.proxy.http_port",             0);
pref("network.proxy.ssl",                   "");
pref("network.proxy.ssl_port",              0);
pref("network.proxy.socks",                 "");
pref("network.proxy.socks_port",            0);
pref("network.proxy.socks_version",         5);
pref("network.proxy.proxy_over_tls",        true);
pref("network.proxy.no_proxies_on",         "");
```

To actually make use of them [install the official `puppeteer` node.js package with Firefox as selected product](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer#q-which-firefox-version-does-puppeteer-use) (note that `puppeteer-firefox` is deprecated). Then preferences can be specified via `extraPrefsFirefox` for the call to `puppeteer.launch()`. [Here an example for the necessary steps](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/examples/cross-browser.js#L20) from the puppeteer repository.

Comment: Hey, can you please explain how & what is pref ?

Comment: The proxy type & proxyDNS doesn't seem to work !

extraPrefsFirefox: {
   'network.proxy.proxyType': 'manual',
   'network.proxy.proxyDNS': true,
   'network.proxy.socks': 'localhost',
   'network.proxy.socks_port': 9050,
   'network.proxy.socks_version': 5,
   'network.proxy.proxy_over_tls': true,
   'network.proxy.no_proxies_on': 'localhost, 127.0.0.1',
  }

Answer (score 3):

With Yevhen's example, you may run into issue's using the import statement.  Instead I recommend using the following:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const { proxyRequest } = require('puppeteer-proxy');
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I did in fact need to switch to const.

Answer (score 0):

[Henrik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63353473/984407) got me on the right track.  Here's what worked for me

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  product: 'firefox',
  extraPrefsFirefox: {
    'network.proxy.type': 1,
    'network.proxy.http': 'localhost',
    'network.proxy.http_port': 8080,
    'network.proxy.ssl': 'localhost',
    'network.proxy.ssl_port': 8080,

    // 'network.proxy.share_proxy_settings': true,
    // note: this setting doesn't work with puppeteer.  When I inspected
    // the preferences saved in the profile directory, it seems this
    // setting is used by firefox to internally set the ssl proxy
    // preferences. This internal process doesn't occur with puppeteer
    // so instead we need to declare the ssl prefs separately.
  },
})
```

To find which key/value pairs I needed for the desired preferences, I visited about:config and filtered by 'network.proxy'.  I'd then manually change the preferences I cared about via the gui and checked back in about:config to see what values were modified.  For instance `'network.proxy.type': 1` corresponds to the gui's `Manual proxy configuration` radio button.